# Automatically adjust map zoom to when marker added or deleted

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I want to adjust map zoom at max where all markers can accommodate in it, I am able to add new markers and adjust zooming level with following code,

```
bounds.extend(markerPosition);
googleMap.fitBounds(bounds);
```

but I want this work in reverse too, like if I remove marker from map zooming level should be adjusted automatically.

Can we do it using Google "Bounds" API ?

Please help....

Comment: You can't "remove" a LatLng from a `google.maps.LatLngBounds` object, only add them by calling `extend`.  To recreate the bounds without the marker, remove the marker from the map, then iterate through all the existing markers adding them to an empty `google.maps.LatLngBounds` object by calling the `extend` method, then call `map.fitBounds` with that new bounds as the argument.

Comment: ok... so there is only way to get this done?

Comment: thanks for suggestion.... @geocodezip..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For overcoming this issues what I have done is, simply written a `resetMapBounds()` function as follows and called it everytime marker is added,edited or deleted and also adjusted zoom level as I required in it.

```
function resetMapBounds(){
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for(var i=0;i<markers.length;i++){
        bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);  
    if(map.getZoom()>18){
        map.setZoom(18);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Worked for me on ionic 3. Thanks!